# Как подключить css документ к html?

Tags: html

Как подключить к html css документ? Пожалуйста, помогите. (Извиняюсь, я новичок )

Comment: Вам необходимо в `head` прописать `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="ТУТ_ПУТЬ_К_ФАЙЛУ_CSS">`

Answer (score 4):

**Подключаем CSS к HTML.**

Допустим у тебя есть основная папка сайта, назовем ее «WEBSITE» 
В ней должны лежать все папки с файлами CSS и HTML файлами, и т.д.

Папку со CSS стилями назовем «CSS_KATALOG»

Файл со стилями который нужно подключить назовем «STYLES»

Путь к папке с файлом CSS нужно указать начиная с точки.

**Пример 1:**

```
./CSS_KATALOG/STYLES.css

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS_KATALOG/STYLES.css">
```

Если файл CSS лежит в месте с файлами HTML, то путь указываем через
две точки, с названием основной папки. Выглядит вот так:

**Пример 2:**

```
../WEBSITE/STYLES.css

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../WEBSITE/STYLES.css">
```

Answer (score 3):

Есть 3 и более способов подключения CSS

Внутренние таблицы стилей - использование атрибута style в начальном теге HTML.
Встроенные таблицы стилей - использование элемента  в разделе заголовка документа.
Внешние таблицы стилей - использование элемента , указывающего на внешний файл CSS.

Самый распространенный этот:

```
<head>
  <title>HTML страница</title>
  <style>
    body { background-color: YellowGreen; }
    p { color: #fff; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  <p>Параграф</p>
  <div>Текст</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Про [все спрособы подключения CSS к HTML](https://domhtml.ru/kak-podklyuchit-css-k-html/) я читал на этом сайте